# Error - This app is not configured for Android push. - Android - Urban Airship

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I have followed following steps to setup urban airship to test Push Notification.

Step 1: Created Free Trial account in https://go.urbanairship.com

Step 2: Created API Key and Project ID using Google API Console 
I followed steps from https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+Android%3A+GCM+Push

Step 3: Downloaded client library jar from urbanairship.com/resources

But now,

Step 4: I went to urban airship site and clicked "Create Application", and it suggested as "GCM support is now available. Contact support to request access."

I am clicking "Test Push Notification" but it shows "This app is not configured for Android push"

I tried most of the things but could not do it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just says in the doc you provided you need to contact support to enable GCM support.
Just to clarify, android used to have another way to handle push notifications that is now deprecated and you cant even sign to use it anymore.
So just contact support to see if they enable GCM support to your app.

Comment: I have sent email but no reply from them :(